# Authentication to use Teams incoming webhook

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm implementing a microsoft teams incoming webhook and I got worried about some bad guy getting the webhook link and sending spams, getting messages from the team and so on. So I'd like to know how secure this feature is? Is there anything that I can do to improve the webhook security?

Comment: Please refer this blog(https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/bring-microsoft-teams-incoming-webhook-security-next-level-kinzelin?msclkid=58f6ddafd0eb11eca9ccc0356553ed5c) which explains how to increase Teams incoming webhook security with Azure Logic App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring Microsoft Teams Incoming Webhook security to the next level using Azure Logic Apps:

It provides following security levels:

1. **Better control over who can create and use a webhook:**
   You can rely on Azure RBAC built-in roles for Azure Logic App to define your access policy. The configuration of the webhook is done in Azure and no configuration information is available from Microsoft Teams.
2. **More options to authenticate the event emitter:** There are different ways to authenticate an emitter and Azure Logic App provides a wide range of options to do that - These methods come in addition to the SAS signature or can replace it.
   To name the most requested one in the context of incoming webhooks, we have:

- Source IP white listing
- Basic authentication / Http headers acces keys
- Azure AD OAuth2.0 token

3. **Protect users from the content published into Teams:**
   With Azure Logic App, you will capture all requests to the webhook because you have control over the endpoint (versus incoming webhooks hosted and exposed via the O365 platform) - When the workflow is triggered, you can add actions steps to your workflow to:

- Validate the schema of the payload (in case an inappropriate JSON
  content is pushed)
- Log this request into an external system - e.g.
  you can push this payload or log this event into Azure Monitor and
  process the content in Azure Sentinel using Logic App built-in
  connectors.
- Map / aggregate / curate / enrich / .... the incoming
  content and format the message to be pushed in Teams using Adaptive Cards.

Reference doc: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/bring-microsoft-teams-incoming-webhook-security-next-level-kinzelin/?msclkid=58f6ddafd0eb11eca9ccc0356553ed5c